# Using DOM to find last row in HTML table

Tags: html, vbscript

I'm developing a macro in Macro Express Pro that uses VBScript to scrub an HTML table to gather data. The data I'm gathering is in the FLN column. I want to build a list that the user can select from using the FLN, then they can gather the rest of the details within the row to use in other applications. The list looks like this:

[image]

My issue is that the list is only showing seven line items. The table I'm using for this example has eight lines. What is happening is I'm looping through to create this list, but when I get done copying the last FLN and go to the next row in the table (highlighted in yellow), I get an object required error.

[image]

I need to be able to read this line so that I can capture all rows in the table, then exit the loop when I reach the highlighted line. Unfortunately, the creators of the site with the table never named the table. There is a `div` that has an ID to it (`div id="pnlBtn"`). I've tried finding this ID, and receive an object error.

[image]

I am currently trying to find the last row in the table, but this is giving me an object error. I know the `objIE.document` part of my code is working as I was able to produce the list above. This was done by setting the counter `I` in the `Do Until...Loop` to 8, which only produces seven lines. If I set `I` to 9, I get an object error.

Here's the code I'm working with:

```
   tdNode = 50

   FLNDCC = objIE.Document.GetElementsByTagName("table")(0).GetElementsByTagName("td")(tdNode).GetElementsByClassName("txt_input1")(0).Value
   I = 1
   List = ""
   intExitCount = 1
   Do Until I = 8
      If FLNDCC = NewFLNDCC Then
         Exit Do
      End If
      If NewFLNDCC <> "" Then
         FLNDCC = NewFLNDCC
      End If

      FLNDCC = I & ". " & FLNDCC
      List = List & FLNDCC & vbCrLf
      FLNDCC = Replace(FLNDCC, I & ". ", "")

      TestRow = objIE.document.getElementsByTagName("tr")
      For j = 0 To TestRow.length
          MsgBox j
      Next

      I = I + 1

      NewFLNDCC = objIE.Document.GetElementsByTagName("table")(0).GetElementsByTagName("td")(tdNode).GetElementsByClassName("txt_input1")(0).Value

      If IsEmpty(NewFLNDCC) = True Then
         Exit Do
      End If

      intExitCount = intExitCount + 1
      If intExitCount = 10 Then
         MsgBox "Do loop in VERIFY_HOV subroutine stuck in a loop." & vbCrLf & "Please submit an issue request with this message.", 48, "Stuck in Do Loop"
         SetEverythingToNothing
      End If
   Loop
   If I > 1 Then
      Opt = InputBox("Please select the FLNDCC you want to work with:" & vbNewLine & List & vbNewLine, "Select an FLNDCC")
      If IsEmpty(Opt) = True Then
         Wscript.Echo "EXIT"
         SetEverythingToNothing
      End If
      Opt = Opt - 1
      tdNode = 50 + (Opt * 21)
   Else
      tdNode = 50
   End If
   FLNDCC = objIE.Document.GetElementsByTagName("table")(0).GetElementsByTagName("td")(tdNode).GetElementsByClassName("txt_input1")(0).Value
```

Is there a foolproof way to find the last row of a table that doesn't produce an object error?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution. I didn't need to find the last row (highlighted in yellow), I just needed to avoid the error. The line that was creating the error was:

```
NewFLNDCC = objIE.Document.GetElementsByTagName("table")(0).GetElementsByTagName("td")(tdNode).GetElementsByClassName("txt_input1")(0).Value
```

On my ninth run through the loop, I was unable to find the `txt_input1` value because it wasn't there. This gave me an object error. Here's how I solved it:

```
On Error Resume Next
   NewFLNDCC = objIE.Document.GetElementsByTagName("table")(0).GetElementsByTagName("td")(tdNode).GetElementsByClassName("txt_input1")(0).Value
On Error goto 0
```

Now, I can have `I` set to 100 and, even though there are only 8 visible lines, it will kick out once `txt_input1` is no longer available and print the list with all 8 lines.